# What is the most appropriate logic to add rows in table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql

I have following table structure (simplified to make essential things clear), which lists Top 3 bank customers in each category of loan and branch of the bank. SNO column is rank of the customer, value of which is up to 3.

| Loan Category | SNO | Branch | Customer Name | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Home Loan | 1 | abc | Piyush | 10000 |
| Home Loan | 2 | abc | Shyam | 5000 |
| Home Loan | 3 | abc | Kamal | 2000 |
| Home Loan | 1 | xyz | Xman | 50000 |
| Home Loan | 2 | xyz | Shyam | 20000 |
| Auto Loan | 1 | abc | Birendra | 10000 |
| Personal Loan | 1 | xyz | Gyan | 5000 |
| Personal Loan | 2 | xyz | Prakash | 2000 |

I am trying to make another table such that, If there are less than 3 customers in each loan category and branch, Insert a dummy row for each branch and category with values of customer name and amount as NULL.
Essentially, I am trying to get following table.

| Loan Category | SNO | Branch | Customer Name | Amount |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Home Loan | 1 | abc | Piyush | 10000 |  |
| Home Loan | 2 | abc | Shyam | 5000 |  |
| Home Loan | 3 | abc | Kamal | 2000 |  |
| Home Loan | 1 | xyz | Xman | 50000 |  |
| Home Loan | 2 | xyz | Shyam | 20000 |  |
| Home Loan | 3 | xyz |  |  | added row |
| Auto Loan | 1 | abc | Birendra | 10000 |  |
| Auto Loan | 2 | abc |  |  | added row |
| Auto Loan | 3 | abc |  |  | added row |
| Auto Loan | 1 | xyz |  |  | added row |
| Auto Loan | 2 | xyz |  |  | added row |
| Auto Loan | 3 | xyz |  |  | added row |
| Personal Loan | 1 | xyz | Gyan | 5000 |  |
| Personal Loan | 2 | xyz | Prakash | 2000 |  |
| Personal Loan | 3 | xyz |  |  | added row |
| Personal Loan | 1 | abc |  |  | added row |
| Personal Loan | 2 | abc |  |  | added row |
| Personal Loan | 3 | abc |  |  | added row |

I have solved this problem by using Loop iterating over all category and branch and inserting dummy row, if max(sno) < 3 for each category/branch. But, I am looking for appropriate logic without iterating over all category and branch. In my actual table, there are thousands of branch values and more than 100 categories. So, iterating over all combination of category and branch is very expensive in terms of performance.

I need to write some good logic preferably using SQL constructs only or not using any loop.

Comment: "table structure (simplified to make essential things clear), which lists Top 3 bank customers in each category of loan and branch of the bank. "  This is itself a flawed design.  You'd have to be constantly checking and possibly updating that table every time a customer takes a new loan or makes a payment on an existing loan.  Not to mention the effect of applying accrued interest to the loan balance. You shouldn't be storing that which can (and should be) calculated at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So you must have some tables where `branch` and `category` is listed in single or multiple tables. Lets take it as your `branch` and `category` tables and you must have some query which produced the result mentioned in the question. Lets call it `your_query`.

You need to generate 3 records per branch per category.

```
Select c.category as loan_category,
       L.lvl as sno, 
       B.branch,
       Q.cutomername,
       Q.amount
  From category c 
  Cross join branch b
  Cross Join (select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 3) l 
  Left Join your_query q on q.branch = c.branch 
                        and q.category = c.category
                        and l.lvl = q.sno
 Ordet by c.category, B.branch, L.lvl
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much.